# Entity Framework convert string value to datetime

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

I have a table storing a list of dates & time (dd/MM/yyyy) in string format.

What I am trying to do is order the data by `DateTime` descending, the code below worked just fine but it just orders it by date (dd), So I have to convert it to Datetime to do the right job.

```
casesBindingSource.DataSource = db.casesSet
                                  .Where(x => x.casestatus == "شفيت")
                                  .OrderByDescending(c => c.dateofrecovery)
                                  .ToList();
```

Comment: What's the type of `dateofrecovery`?

Comment: @devNull String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try first calling tolist and then running orderby. I know it is a bit inefficient, however it is worth giving a try.

```
casesBindingSource.DataSource = db.casesSet
                                  .Where(x => x.casestatus == "شفيت")
                                  .ToList()
                                  .OrderByDescending(c => DateTime.ParseExact(c.dateofrecovery, "dd/MM/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Year)
                                  .ThenByDescending(c => DateTime.ParseExact(c.dateofrecovery, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Month)
                                  .ThenByDescending(c => DateTime.ParseExact(c.dateofrecovery, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Day);
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
casesBindingSource.DataSource = db.casesSet
                                  .Where(x => x.casestatus == "شفيت")
                                  .OrderByDescending(c => DateTime.ParseExact(c.dateofrecovery, "dd/MM/yyyy", Nothing))
                                  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:
`.OrderByDescending(c => DateTime.ParseExact(c.dateofrecovery, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))`

Comment: I have already tried that, it shows this error: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ParseExact.

Comment: Perhaps using `.Select()` may help in order to map your entity with dateofrecovery as a `string` to a new entity with dateofrecovery as a `DateTime`, order them, and then re-map to your original entity type. This approach may not be the best in terms of permormance though.